# How to remove a nested property from Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to remove a specific property from json.

The json was like as below and I want to remove "image" attribute.

```
{ 
  "properties": {    
    "docker": {
      "password": {
        "value": "ei"
      },
      "image": {
        "value": ".0.0-11-g1"
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I tried as below

```
var obj = JObject.Parse("json");
obj["properties"]["docker"]["image"].Remove();
```

But I am getting exception

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: `JsonExtensions.RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40118119/3744182) to [Remove fields form JObject dynamically using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40116088/3744182) may be useful to automatically remove the `JProperty` when trying to delete its value.

Comment: @DanielA.White I am getting the exception as _Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException: 'Cannot add or remove items from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty._

Comment: While marking as duplicate, if you provide the link of the answer, that would be helpful :-)

Comment: I used the already available answer as below and it works fine. But don't we have other way like i tried?  `obj .Descendants()
                .OfType<JProperty>()
                .Where(attr => attr.Name.StartsWith("image"))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(attr => attr.Remove());`

Comment: But with that solution I have **image** attribute in different levels, and I don't want all of that to be deleted. With the above solution, all **image** attributes will be get deleted. Hence this thread is not duplicate

Comment: obj.SelectToken("properties.docker.image")?.Parent.Remove();